# Python 3.X random.choice for object array with sub array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Provided the object array:

```
textures = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "cement",
        "apply_to": ["wall", "basement"],
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "fabric",
        "apply_to": ["window"],
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "brick",
        "apply_to": ["wall"],
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...
]
```

Suppose I wanted to pick a random object out of that array with the keyword 'wall' in that apply_to property?

So that I get either id (1,3) returned at random?

How can I use 'random.choice' or another random function to do so?

Comment: If you just take a random object, what's the probability of it having 'wall' (or any other such value)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wall_textures = [texture for texture in textures if 'wall' in texture['apply_to']]
random_wall_texture = random.choice(wall_textures)
```

Agree that not the best way but this will let you make the choice randomly

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do this selection a small number of times, [Arunbh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77861453/843953) to filter only those textures that contain `'wall'` in their `apply_to` key is the right way.

However, if you're trying to do this more than a few times, I would say that this is the wrong data structure for the task you are trying to do. You should instead create a dictionary that groups all textures by their `apply_to` value, and call `random.choice` on the group that you care about.

Do this one time:

```
group_by_apply_to = {}
for texture in textures:
    for a in texture['apply_to']:
        if a not in group_by_apply_to:
            group_by_apply_to[a] = []

        group_by_apply_to[a].append(texture)
```

Now, you have the following `group_by_apply_to`:

```
{

 'wall': [
           {'id': 1, 'name': 'cement', 'apply_to': ['wall', 'basement']},
           {'id': 3, 'name': 'brick', 'apply_to': ['wall']}
         ],
 'basement': [
               {'id': 1, 'name': 'cement', 'apply_to': ['wall', 'basement']}
             ],
 'window': [
             {'id': 2, 'name': 'fabric', 'apply_to': ['window']}
           ]
}
```

And whenever you want a texture that can apply to something, you can simply do (e.g. for wall):

```
random_wall_texture = random.choice(group_by_apply_to['wall'])
```